# resource deployments/my-app missing the kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration annotation which is required by kubectl

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to achieve use `kubectl apply -f` without this warning:

```
PS C:\Users\me> kubectl apply -f manifest.yml
Warning: resource deployments/myapp is missing the kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration annotation which is required by kubectl apply. kubectl apply should only be used on resources created declaratively by either kubectl create --save-config or kubectl apply. The missing annotation will be patched automatically.
```

I tried fixing the issue by using this manifest file:

```yaml
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: cool-app
  labels:
    app: cool-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: cool-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: cool-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: cool-app
          image: cool:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Always
```

But no luck, still getting this warning. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the warning happens because it's the first time you are creating the resource. therefore there is no annotation you're kubectl can use to figure out what to patch and change on the client side.

you'll always get the warning locally unless you either get the currently rendered manifest from k8s with the correct annotation from the api, change it and reapply it, or add an empty annotation yourself to your manifest.

like this for example:

```
annotations:
  kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: ""
```

another solution would be to not use client-side apply but have k8s apply the manifest server-side. so you do not need the annotation yourself. which is recommended as of late anyways.

so you would use `kubectl apply -f $yourmanifest.yaml --server-side`

for more information on server-side apply you can check the documentation [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/server-side-apply/)